# Python: don't understand difference

Tags: python

I am really sorry about my python understanding and about my English.
I just started to learn Python and really dont understand difference between two next code:

```
def arrayCheck(nums):
    """
    find nums
    """
    for i in range(len(nums)-2):
        if nums[i]==1 and nums[i+1]==2 and nums[i+2]==3:
            return True
            return False

result = arrayCheck([1, 1, 2, 3, 1])
print(result)
```

When run this code the result is True

And the next one:

```
def arrayCheck(nums):
    """
    find nums
    """
    for i in range(len(nums)-2):
        if nums[i]==1 and nums[i+1]==2 and nums[i+2]==3:
            return True
        else:
            return False

result = arrayCheck([1, 1, 2, 3, 1])
print(result)
```

The second code return False.

Why?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you intend the first code segment to have `return True` and `return False` on the same indentation level?

Answer (score 2):

The first code can return only `True` or `None`. After the return statement the function ends so the first code never reach the `return False` statement.
The second code will return `False` if the first 3 items are not 1, 2 and 3 since if the condition does not hold it returns `False`.

I would actually assume this is the code you are interested in -

```
def arrayCheck(nums):
    """
    find nums
    """
    for i in range(len(nums)-2):
        if nums[i]==1 and nums[i+1]==2 and nums[i+2]==3:
            return True
    return False
```

See Python control flow [here](https://python.swaroopch.com/control_flow.html).

Answer (score 1):

In python the indentation matters, and return will break out the function so, in the first codeblock you have

```py
if nums[i]==1 and nums[i+1]==2 and nums[i+2]==3:
   return True
   return False
```

The two `return` are on the same indent level so if the condition is met It will go to first line, `return True`,
see return and break out of the function ignoring everything afterwards
but in the second codeblock
you have

```py
if nums[i]==1 and nums[i+1]==2 and nums[i+2]==3:
   return True
else:
   return False
```

so if the condition is true it will return true and break out of the function
but if the condition is not true it will return false and break out of the function so it only does one of the iterations you are trying to do.

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, this would be the solution :

```py
def arrayCheck(nums):
    """
    find nums
    """
    found = False
    for i in range(len(nums)-2):
        if nums[i]==1 and nums[i+1]==2 and nums[i+2]==3:
            found = True
    return found

result = arrayCheck([1, 1, 2, 3, 1])
print(result)
```

This works because it allows the function to check over every iteration in the for loop and it will return true if the numbers were found

Answer (score 1):

In the first code, **if** condition has no else part. While in the 2nd code, **if** condition has a else part. 
So when **if** condition is false in the first code, it is going for second iteration and if condition getting True as per the input and it is returning True.
But in the second code, **if** condition is false and it is going to else part and returning False.

Comment: Since there is a `return` statement at the end of the `if`, it isn't compulsory to add an `else`. The issue comes from the indentation. Check @tom-ron 's answer, there is no `else` but the code still runs as expected

Answer (score 0):

In first code `return False` will never execute because it is inside the if condition and before it another `return` statement `return True`. After returning the function execution will stop.

In the second code if condition fails for the first time the function execution will stop because of `return False` in else condition.